# How do I check if string::append() is going to fail

Tags: c++, windows, string, exception, append

I am writing a code in which I need to create a `std::string` by appending data to it(here data means logs of an application). But string also has its limitation of size. I have written the code in `try-catch` block and when `append()` fails, it throws exception. I need to check before `append()` whether attaching new string will cause any `exception`, since once exception is thrown, it clears the data from string.
I want to check if attaching new string will cause any exception and if yes then write the data to a file and clear the string for next input.
As it is an application log, I do not know what the final size will be. So I am trying to make code less vulnerable to above explained problem.
I have checked one condition as follows:
If "`current_string_size + to_be_attached_string_size exceeds string.max_size()`" then write the code into file.
If "not" then append to_be_attached_string to current_string.
But it is failing somewhere.
What condition I need to check?

Comment: *But it is failing somewhere* in which sense? can you provide a minimum reproducing code? `string::max_size()` is usually pretty large ...

Comment: Are we talking about [`std::basic_string::max_size()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/max_size) and `std::basic_string::append()`? The former usually isn't something you'd ever need to worry about, and the latter has the strong exception safety guarantee since C++11.

Comment: Trying to fill all RAM before writing out a log is not a good idea - you risk having a OS low-memory routine start terminating applications, or a crash due to memory over-commit, and with more regular writes log content can be a useful way to check the program's still running ok, and/or help debug a crash.  At most, buffer something on the order of 16kb then `write` to the file - much more than that's unlikely to improve performance significantly.

Comment: @Walter: I have written code like:

string strData;

void fun(input_string)
{
 try
 {
  if ((strData.size() + input_string_size) >= strData.max_size())
  {
   // Write strData to file and clear strData for next input.
                        return;
  }
  strData.append(input_string);
 }
 catch(exception e)
 {
  return;
 }
}

Comment: How about simply opening a file and writing to it? The standard library provides buffering for you. You can make it a global singleton, or pass it by pointer to objects which require logging.

Comment: @T.C.: Sorry, I did not get you. What solution should I use then?

Comment: @Tony D: I need to minimize file I/O, that is why I was writing to file it at the end.

Comment: @SamL - `max_size()` is pretty useless as it just gives you an upper limit on the theoretical size. Allocating more will *always* throw an exception. Usually you cannot get even close to this value if you have some other data structures in your program.

Comment: @Bo Persson: Yes, I have tried by calling `resize()` and by giving `max_size()` as a parameter. But this also throws `bad_alloc` exception.

Answer (score 2):

Use C++11 and simply put your `string::append()` attempt into **`try catch` block** (as you initially did). [If an exception is thrown for any reason, this function has no effect (strong exception guarantee)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/append), contrary to your opinion ("since once exception is thrown, it clears the data from string") or pre C++11.

```
std::string orig, to_append;
try {
  orig.append(to_append);
} catch(...) {
  write_to_file(orig);
  orig = std::move(to_append);
}
```

---

However, writing a log into a `string` makes no sense (unless you want to read from that `string` from within the same program, but then this is no longer a log).
Following the suggestion from [Peter Eke](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4366156/peter-eke), it makes more sense to directly write to an `std::ofstream`:

```
void add_to_log(std::string const&msg, bool flush=false)
{
  static std::ofstream logfile;
  if(!logfile)
    logfile.open("logfile.txt");
  logfile << msg;
  if(flush) logfile << std::flush;
}
```

The `std::ofstream` will buffer the output anyway, i.e. only write to disc if the buffer becomes full or if you force it to (via `flush`).

Comment: So you mean to say, I should use `std::ofstream` instead of `std::string`? If yes then, is there any memory limit to store data into `std::ofstream` like `std::string`? If there is a limit then the same problem arises again. Here i need to check if `std::ofstream` is full or not. If it is full then write to file.

Comment: Sam, `std::ofstream` writes to file, it cannot be full (unless your disc is, but then you cannot make any outputs anyway ...).